# SAS proc sql - is this the correct usage?

Tags: sql, sas

This works but wanted a health check as to if i have done this correct with proc sql connect to i.e do i need to have separate "select * from connection to's"?

```
proc sql;
connect to database (database=test user="&srvuser" password="&srvpass") ;
create table bob as 
select t1._ as bob1 
      ,t2._ as bob2 
      ,t3._ as bob3
      ,t1._-t2._ as bob4
from (select * from connection to database
(Select count(*)
        from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
        where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'D' and RR_MSG_SEQ_NO = 1)) t1
,(select * from connection to database
(Select count(*)
        from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
        where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R')) t2
,(select * from connection to database
(Select count(*)
        from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
        where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R' and RR_MSG_TIME_STAMP IS NULL)) t3;
disconnect from database;
quit;
run;
```

Thanks

Comment: To avoid confusing you (and the parser) the first thing to change is to give names to your unnamed variables. It looks like you are counting on something assigning them a name of `_`.  For example:  `count(*) as R_COUNT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are pulling from the same database just push the join into the database. While you are at it assign names to the variables when you create them.

```
create table bob as 
select bob1 
     , bob2 
     , bob3
     , bob1-bob2 as bob4
from connection to database 
(select t1.bob1
      , t2.bob2
      , t3.bob3 
 from
  (select count(*) as bob1
   from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
   where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'D' and RR_MSG_SEQ_NO = 1
  ) t1
, (select count(*) as bob2
   from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
   where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R'
   ) t2
, (select count(*) as bob3
   from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
   where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R' and RR_MSG_TIME_STAMP IS NULL
  ) t3
);
```

Since you are generating those counts from querying the same table (dataset) you can to it with a single query by using CASE instead of WHERE.

```
(select sum(case when (RR_MSG_CODE  = 'D' and RR_MSG_SEQ_NO = 1) then 1 
            else 0 end) as bob1
      , sum(case when (RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R') then 1 
            else 0 end) as bob2
      , sum(case when (RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R' and RR_MSG_TIME_STAMP IS NULL) then 1 
            else 0 end) as bob3
 from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
)
```

Although you might want to add the common conditions to the where clause to have it process fewer records.

```
where RR_MSG_CODE in ('R','D')
```

Answer (score 0):

The query could work that way, but a cleaner approach might be to do everything server side in one query over a single  `connection to`

```
create table want as
select bob1, bob2, bob3, bob1-bob2 as bob4 from connection to database 
(
 select 
  (select count(*) from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
   where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'D' and RR_MSG_SEQ_NO = 1) as bob1,
  (select count(*) from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
   where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R') as bob2,
  (select count(*) from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG 
   where RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R' and RR_MSG_TIME_STAMP IS NULL) as bob3
)
```

A slightly different approach would return one row per count.  The result set could be transposed in SAS.  There `where` clause could be left off, but the remote system would have to traverse every record in `IMAGE_MSG_LOG` and lose ability to utilize any indices that the `where` might leverage.

```
create table want as
select * from connection to database 
(
  select 
    case 
      when RR_MSG_CODE  = 'D' and RR_MSG_SEQ_NO = 1 then 'D1'
      when RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R' and RR_MSG_TIME_STAMP IS NULL then 'RNULL'
      when RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R' then 'RNOTNULL'
      else 'NOCAT'
    end
    as category,
    count(*) as category_count
  from DAVE.IMAGE_MSG_LOG
  where 
      (RR_MSG_CODE  = 'D' and RR_MSG_SEQ_NO = 1)
   or (RR_MSG_CODE  = 'R')
  group by category
)
```

After transpose

- `bob1` is `D1`
- `bob2` is `RNULL` + `RNOTNULL`
- `bob3` is `RNULL`
- `bob4` is `bob1`-`bob2`